# What is the relation between the R class in Android framework, and the R.java file in our projects?

Tags: android, r.java-file

What kind of class is the R class in Android?

I am not talking about the R.java file in your project which contains the id's of the application resource objects.

I am talking about [this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html)?

Does this R class have any relation with the R.java file mentioned above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android R is system wide.
Your app's R is private to your app.

Comment: OK but basically R files store the id's of the application resources? The system-wide R stores the id's of the resources in the entire Android platform, while our application's R stores the id's of the resources of our application. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

**R.java** which is Automatically System generated file it contains the id of each resources used in Application which is used to make refrence. `R.class contains IDs` for all your android resources.